# Linphone SIP client not working Behind NAT

Tags: sip, voip, nat, linphone

I am trying to test Linphone in public network with both clients are
behind NAT and my sip server is having public IP. All my SIP
signalling with SIP server is working fine but end to end Linphone
clients are not able to receive voice packets for communication.

Please suggest what is the approach to get this scenario working.

P.S: I have also enabled STUN, ICE still not working.

Comment: I have tried this with Asterisk and Kamailio SIP servers, with both SIP servers same issue(no voice at both ends) when both clients are behind NAT in public network. Ex: Airtel network in Delhi, India.

Comment: sorry for out of context question, I've used Easylinphone library (which uses Linphone SDK), with my own sever configuration, my audio/video call drops after 30/32 seconds. any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: @ShivBuyya any solution did you found yet?

Comment: @Solaiman Hossain , i removed google-services.json file which prevented me in call drop at 32 seconds . And this file was used for firebase, in my scenario firebase was not required and so call is fixed .